# In Minecraft 1.0, is sleep changed to not require everyone to sleep?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the beta-versions of Minecraft that I played (up to 1.8.1, I only dabbled with 1.9), everyone on the server had to go to sleep in order for the game to skip ahead to the next day.

In 1.0 final, we noticed that when one of us went to sleep, the server skipped ahead to daytime even though the other person was still mining.

Is this a feature (so that we can rely on it), or is it a bug?

Comment: [status-norepro] here.  I can lay in bed all I want, but morning doesn't come if there is someone awake.

Comment: Was the other person in Netherworld? One cannot sleep there so only people in the Overworld need to be in bed to skip the night.

Comment: No, he wasn't, but I didn't post all the details in the question. I seemed to recall having the same experience in vanilla minecraft SMP 1.0, but I retested yesterday, seems it must be a bug in the bukkit version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not skip to  morning if I sleep in my vanilla Minecraft 1.0 server so long as someone else is logged in and active.

I suspect this is intentional and unlikely to change - if one person is, say, hunting skeletons on the surface, and another sleeps, should the first player be unable to continue his activities due to early sunrise? Or will they somehow be experiencing worlds that are out of synch?

Comment: so then what happens to the second player? does he get a msg that says he cannot sleep? or does he wakeup and find it still night? if its the second result, does this offer him any benifits? ie: healing or something?

Comment: @Ender huh? I don't understand your question. If I sleep and my friend is logged into the server, I simply remain in the bed paused until dawn pops me out. If my friend also sleeps, it fades to black and becomes day. I sometimes pop into bed while I head afk, the chat window pops up while in bed so I can keep an eye on things.

Comment: so if you sleep, and others dont, your... stuck there, until dawn? why not just stand in a corner safe? I'm failing to see the major point here? can you get up if you choose?

Comment: @Ender you can get up any time you want. There's no real advantage to laying in a bed versus standing in a corner, it just looks less odd to people walking past. The main advantage of beds is if everyone agrees to sleep, time will pass.